# bash - redirect STDERR into log function

Tags: bash

I have a log function:

```
log() {
    if [[ "$#" -ne 2 ]];then
        printf "[%s] %s\n" 'error' 'log function requires two arguments'
        printf "%s\n" 'usage: log [level] "message"'
        printf "%s\n" 'e.g: log error "this is my error"'
        exit 1
    elif [[ "$1" == 'info' ]]; then
        printf "[%s] %s: %s %s\n" "info" "$(basename $0)" "$curr_date" "${2}"  &> >(tee -a "$log_file")
    elif [[ "$1" == 'warn' ]]; then
        printf "[%s] %s: %s %s\n" "warn" "$(basename $0)" "$curr_date" "${2}"  &> >(tee -a "$log_file")
    elif [[ "$1" == 'error' ]]; then
        printf "[%s] %s: %s\n" "error" "$(basename $0)" "$curr_date" "${2}"  &> >(tee -a "$log_file")
    elif [[ "$1" == 'debug' ]]; then
        printf "[%s] %s: %s %s\n" "debug" "$(basename $0)" "$curr_date" "${2}"  &> >(tee -a "$log_file")
    else
        printf "[%s] %s %s\n" 'error' 'unable to log with level' "'${1}'"
        printf "%26s '%s' '%s' '%s' '%s'\n" 'allowed levels are' 'info' 'warn' 'error' 'debug'
    fi
}
```

This is in an external file, and is sourced in whatever script needs it:

```
source log
```

What I would like to do, if possible, is redirect STDERR into `log error <message>` so that I don't have to check each and every commands exit code for errors. Something like `exec 2> log error` so that it captures every error message.

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Comment: If you want to redirect standard error to that functionality, then I think you'll need to redirect, probably using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), into a `while read -r line; do log "$line"; done` operation.  The primary caveat is that as shown, the log function gets a single long string argument.  However, it isn't clear that it's safe to use `do log $line; done` instead because you don't know what might be in the error messages. I'd be tempted to use a Perl script or similar to receive and parse and log the information instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a `trap` *below* the definition of your log function:

```
# define a trap function
error_handler() {
    log error "I got an error on line:${1}, exit status of last command: ${2}"
    trap - ERR
}

# activate the trap
trap 'error_handler ${LINENO} $?' ERR

#### paste in the following your commands
```

Edit: `trap - ERR` drops the trap, if you intend to use the trap multiple times (if your script doesn't terminate after the first error) just comment it.

Comment: What does the `trap - ERR' do at the end?

Comment: @Simone: Amazing. You've changed my life. Thanks

Comment: @Simone - sorry jumped the gun here. It indeed gives me an error message which is awesome (I wasn't otherwise capturing that) - however it doesn't actually log the error message. Any way to do that? Happy to open another question if you need

Comment: @user6127511 try adding `exec > >(tee -a "$log_file"); exec 2>&1` at the begin of your script, then you can remove `&> >(tee -a "$log_file")` from the log function.